# Convert List of Objects to another type by HQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have the next class that is persisted to a db.

```
class User {
  private long id;

  @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "role_id"))
  @Embedded
  @ElementCollection
  private List<RoleId> roles;
}

class RoleId {
  private String id;
}
```

I want to get the next projection of this class.

```
class UserProjection {
  private long id;
  private List<String> roles;
}
```

Where `List<String> roles` are the collected list of `RoleId.id` of a user.
To do it I wrote the next HQL:

```
select new UserProjection(id, elements(roles)) from User where id = :id
```

Of course it doesn't work due to the roles are RoleId objects. How can I convert `List<RoleId>` to `List<String>` using HQL. Is it possible?

**UPD:**

So, I decided that it's impossible or it's close to impossible. Instead of this I use CriteriaAPI.

Answer (score 0):

You can create constructor of `UserProjection` and make the conversion from `List<RoleId>` into `List<String>` there.

Query should be a little bit another (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor) and [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause)):

```
select new ...UserProjection(u.id, u.roles) from User u join fetch u.roles where u.id = ?1
```

---

I think you can even try to solve your task like [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces.open) (not tested):

```
public interface UserProjection {
    Long getId();
    @Value("#{target.roles.stream().map(RoleId::getId).collect(T(java.util.stream.Collectors).toList())}")
    List<String> getRoles();
}
```

Then use this projection in your repo:

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    List<UserProjection> getById(long id);
}
```

(Please let us know if it work.. )

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I decided to use CriteriaAPI instead.

Comment: @OlegP. which variant doesn't work? First one must work in any way... (did you see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor)?)

Comment: @OlegP. "must work.." with correction: `from User u join fetch u.roles` (I updated the answer)